# Filter Postgre query after percent_rank()

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to figure out how to correctly do this PostgreSQL query.
I have a 'points' column, and I want to run a percent_rank on the points column, and then use a WHERE clause to filter out people below a certain rank AFTER the percent rank has already been calculated. It seems like by default the where clause takes place before the percent_rank, which is fine because I do want to filter out some things before the rank is calculated, but then filter it more after it is calculated.

For example:

```
SELECT name,points,PERCENT_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY points) 
FROM users 
WHERE username IS NOT NULL 
AND is_active = TRUE
```

and then filter this by only people with a percent_rank > .10 or some other filter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a subquery:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM (SELECT name, points, PERCENT_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY points) as prank
      FROM users 
      WHERE username IS NOT NULL AND is_active
     ) u
WHERE prank > 0.10;
```